# Finding Max Sum in Array of Credit Card Numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, return-value

I am interested in finding the credit card number whose digits sum to the largest number. If  more than one has the same largest sum of digits, I want the last one in the list with that sum.

I am trying to write a single function that takes one argument. That argument will be an array  of credit card numbers. Assume the array can have any number of credit card numbers and each one is a string of digits and dashes. The function should return the credit card number that has the largest sum of digits.

Here is what I have so far-

```
var creditCardNumbers = ['5865-2600-5889-0555', '4779-598666-3666', '4252-278553-7978' ,'4556-4242-9283-2260'];

var sums = creditCardNumbers.map(function(f) {
return f.match(/\d/g).reduce(function(sum, num) {
     return sum + parseInt(num);
}, 1);
});
var maxSum = Math.max.apply(Math, sums);


console.log("totalSums = " + (sums) );
console.log("maxSum = " + maxSum );
console.log("Number with the highest sum: " + (sums.creditCardNumbers));
//This last console.log does not work
```

I am having trouble returning the corresponding credit card number with highest sum. If anyone has advice on how to achieve this problem their own way that's great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe something like `creditCardNumbers.reduce(..., {cc: undefined, max: 0}).cc`?

Comment: (I let you figure out the rest ;) )

Comment: I hope this is just a test and not indicative of any actual production code you're using.

Comment: On a side note,Why would you sum credit card digits

Answer (score 1):

Your code might look like this

```
var  ccn = ['5865-2600-5889-0555', '4779-598666-3666', '4252-278553-7978' ,'4556-4242-9283-2260'],
filtered = [],
 ccnSums = ccn.map( e => Array.prototype.reduce.call(e.replace(/-/g,""), (p,c) => 1*p+1*c));
ccnSums.forEach((e,i,a) => a.lastIndexOf(e) == i && filtered.push(e));
```

So from the given data it returns `ccnSums` as `[77, 88, 74, 64]` and `filtered` is also [77, 88, 74, 64] however if i change the 3rd credit card no to '4255-278553-7978' then it returns `ccnSums` as `[77, 88, 77, 64]` and now the `filtered` is `[88, 77, 64]`. I hope this was what you wanted.

Comment: `.replace()` returns an Array, so you don't need `Array.prototype.map.call`. Just do `e.replace(...).map(...)`. Or simply eliminate that inner `.map()`

Comment: Thanks your are right.. corrected accordingly. Now it should be all fine.

Comment: Same with `.reduce()`. You can call it directly on the return value of `.replace()` instead of doing `Array.prototype.reduce.call`.

Comment: @squint this is `String.prototype.replace()` and returns a string hence the `Array.prototype.reduce.call()` is needed.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. Though you could avoid that and the `.map()` by instead doing what the OP was doing originally with `ccn.match(/\d/g).reduce(...`

Comment: I saw OP's way once you indicated. That's also nice and basically doing the same thing. But i think `f.match(/\d/g)` is creating an extra array while `Array.prototype.reduce.call(e.replace(/-/g,"")` is using the existing string as if it's an array so that my Commodore 64 has some memory savings. :)

Comment: Good point. It seems like a good possibility that they reuse substrings of the original when returning the new.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code:

```
var creditCardNumbers = ['5865-2600-5889-0555', '4779-598666-3666', '4252-278553-7978' ,'4556-4242-9283-2260'];

var sums = creditCardNumbers.map(function(f) {
return f.match(/\d/g).reduce(function(sum, num) {
 return sum + parseInt(num);
}, 1);
});
var maxSum = Math.max.apply(Math, sums);


console.log("totalSums = " + (sums) );
console.log("maxSum = " + maxSum );
console.log("Number with the highest sum: " +    (creditCardNumbers[sums.indexOf(maxSum)]));
or,
console.log("Number with the highest sum: " +    (creditCardNumbers[sums.indexOf(Math.max(...sums))]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the trouble is just in "*returning the corresponding credit card number with highest sum*" then why to just not do the following simple thing:

```
...
console.log("Number with the highest sum: " + (creditCardNumbers[sums.indexOf(maxSum)]));
// Number with the highest sum: 4779-598666-3666
```

(or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the following two corrections:

1) Do not pass an initial value to the array reduce method. You are passing an optional init value of 1. It is not needed

2) You have already figured out the max sum. All you need to do is find the index of that max sum from the sums array and use that index to locate the credit card number from the original array. Arrays provide a method called "indexOf". In case there are multiple credit card numbers with the same sum, you want the last one in the list. So use another version of IndexOf function called lastIndexOf.

Here is how your final program will look like:

```
var creditCardNumbers = ['5865-2600-5889-0555', '4779-598666-3666', '4252-    278553-7978' ,'4556-4242-9283-2260']; 

var sums = creditCardNumbers.map(function(f) {
    return f.match(/\d/g).reduce(function(sum, num) {
         return sum + parseInt(num);
    });
});
var maxSum = Math.max.apply(Math, sums);

console.log("totalSums = " + (sums) );
console.log("maxSum = " + maxSum );
var index = sums.lastIndexOf(maxSum.toString());
console.log("Number with the highest sum: " +  creditCardNumbers[index] );
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be another way to do.

```
var a = ["5865-2600-5889-0555", "4779-5989-9666-3666", "4252-278553-7978", "4556-4242-9283-2260"]

function yourFunction (array){
 var temp = _.reduce(arr,function(acc, v) {
     acc[v] = _.sumBy(v, function (v) {
    return !_.isNaN(parseInt(v)) ? parseInt(v) : 0;
   });
  return acc;
 },{});
 return _.invert(temp)[_.max(_.values(temp))];
}
```